# explicitly passing functions in python

Tags: python, function

Out of curiosity is more desirable to explicitly pass functions to other functions, or let the function call functions from within. is this a case of Explicit is better than implicit?

for example (the following is only to illustrate what i mean)

```
def foo(x,y):
    return 1 if x > y else 0

partialfun = functools.partial(foo, 1)

def bar(xs,ys):
    return partialfun(sum(map(operator.mul,xs,ys)))

>>> bar([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
```

--or--

```
def foo(x,y):
    return 1 if x > y else 0

partialfun = functools.partial(foo, 1)

def bar(fn,xs,ys):
    return fn(sum(map(operator.mul,xs,ys)))

>>> bar(partialfun, [1,2,3], [4,5,6])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really any difference between functions and anything else in this situation.  You pass something as an argument if it's a parameter that might vary over different invocations of the function.  If the function you are calling (`bar` in your example) is always calling the same other function, there's no reason to pass that as an argument.  If you need to parameterize it so that you can use many different functions (i.e., `bar` might need to call many functions besides `partialfun`, and needs to know which one to call), then you need to pass it as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, yes, but as always, it depends. What you are illustrating here is known as [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). Generally, it is a good idea, as it allows separation of variability from the logic of a given function. This means, for example, that it will be extremely easy for you to test such code.

```
# To test the process performed in bar(), we can "inject" a function
# which simply returns its argument
def dummy(x):
    return x

def bar(fn,xs,ys):
    return fn(sum(map(operator.mul,xs,ys)))

>>> assert bar(dummy, [1,2,3], [4,5,6]) == 32
```

Comment: thank you for the link to dependency injection. It has certainly clarified a few things (things that I did not even realise I was asking)

Answer (score 2):

It depends very much on the context.

Basically, if the function is an argument to `bar`, then it's the responsibility of the caller to know how to implement that function. `bar` doesn't have to care. But consequently, `bar`'s documentation has to describe what *kind* of function it needs.

Often this is very appropriate. The obvious example is the `map` builtin function. `map` implements the logic of applying a function to each item in a list, and giving back a list of results. `map` itself neither knows nor cares about what the items are, or what the function is doing to them. `map`'s documentation has to describe that it needs a function of one argument, and each caller of `map` has to know how to implement or find a suitable function. But this arrangement is great; it allows you to pass a list of your custom objects, and a function which operates specifically on those objects, and `map` can go away and do its generic thing.

But often this arrangement is inappropriate. A function gives a name to a high level operation and hides the internal implementation details, so you can think of the operation as a unit. Allowing part of its operation to be passed in from outside as a function parameter exposes that it works in a way that uses that function's interface.

A more concrete (though somewhat contrived) example may help. Lets say I've implemented data types representing `Person` and `Job`, and I'm writing a function `name_and_title` for formatting someone's full name and job title into a string, for client code to insert into email signatures or on letterhead or whatever. It's obviously going to take a `Person` and `Job`. It could potentially take a function parameter to let the caller decide how to format the person's name: something like `lambda firstname, lastname: lastname + ', ' + firstname`. But to do this is to expose that I'm representing people's names with a separate first name and last name. If I want to change to supporting a middle name, then either `name_and_title` won't be able to include the middle name, or I have to change the type of the function it accepts. When I realise that some people have 4 or more names and decide to change to storing a list of names, then I definitely have to change the type of function `name_and_title` accepts.

So for your `bar` example, we can't say which is better, because it's an abstract example with no meaning. It depends on whether the call to `partialfun` is an implementation detail of whatever `bar` is supposed to be doing, or whether the call to `partialfun` is something that the caller knows about (and might want to do something else). If it's "part of" `bar`, then it shouldn't be a parameter. If it's "part of" the caller, then it should be a parameter.

It's worth noting that `bar` could have a *huge* number of function parameters. You call `sum`, `map`, and `operator.mul`, which could all be parameterised to make `bar` more flexible:

```
def bar(fn, xs,ys, g, h, i):
    return fn(g(h(i,xs,ys))
```

And the way in which `g` is called on the output of `h` could be abstracted too:

```
def bar(fn, xs, ys, g, h, i, j):
    return fn(j(g, h(i, xs, ys)))
```

And we can keep going on and on, until `bar` doesn't do anything at all, and everything is controlled by the functions passed in, and the caller might as well have just directly done what they want done rather than writing 100 functions to do it and passing those to `bar` to execute the functions.

So there really isn't a definite answer one way or the other that applies all the time. It depends on the particular code you're writing.

Comment: This is a great answer - quite thorough. Although, I'd have liked it if you mentioned unit testing. :o)

Comment: +1 - Thank you for taking the time to run through this! I had got into a habit of passing functions and building up new functions using partial, but I think I have perhaps been doing this when it was not really needed. your sentence 'If it's "part of" bar, then it shouldn't be a parameter. If it's "part of" the caller, then it should be a parameter.' makes a lot sense. Bravo.